# Hibernate doesn't use Firebird sequence, but tries to use a table instead

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

I am trying to insert a new user into a Firebird DB from hibernate with

```
Session session = factory.openSession();

UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
user.setName("Mark");
user.setPassword("1234567");
user.setUserType(1L);

session.beginTransaction();
try {
    session.persist(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception  e) {
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

and my entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAIL")
public class UserDetail
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen", sequenceName = "GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Long userType;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = UserDetailConstraint.MIN_USER_NAME, max = UserDetailConstraint.MAX_USER_NAME)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "HASHED_PASSWORD")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = UserDetailConstraint.MIN_PASSWORD, max = UserDetailConstraint.MAX_PASSWORD)
    private String password;

    public Long getId() { return id;  }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    public Long getUserType() { return userType; }
    public void setUserType(Long userType) { this.userType = userType; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }


    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
}
```

but when hibernate tries to retrieve a new id via generator, it uses

```
select next_val as id_val from GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID with lock
```

but `GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID` is not a table, it is a sequence.

So the program crashes with an error

```
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for 

production use!)
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver] at URL [jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/warehouse]
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=SYSDBA, password=****}
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 5 (min=1)
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator configure
INFO: HHH000107: Forcing table use for sequence-style generator due to pooled optimizer selection where db does not support pooled sequences
апр 26, 2017 5:19:07 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.2.Final
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID with lock
апр 26, 2017 5:19:07 PM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1 execute
ERROR: could not read a hi value
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -204
Table unknown
GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID
At line 1, column 51
```

When I use xml mapping instead of annotations, then everything works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is important Forcing table use for sequence-style generator due to pooled optimizer selection where db does not support pooled sequences, your db is not supporting Sequnce , can you have a look

Comment: @rajadilipkolli Firebird supports sequences, just not pooled sequences.

Comment: If you found a way to solve this other than my solutions, I suggest you post your own answer with that solution (and accept that after the timeout).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to use a firebird generators. Need this.

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID")
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@SequenceGenerator` defaults to an allocation size of 50, which requires pooled sequences. Firebird doesn't support pooled sequences (technically it does, but not in the way Hibernate requires it). Allocation sizes other than 1 trigger Hibernate to use a table based strategy instead.

This is also indicated in the logs:

> апр 26, 2017 5:19:06 PM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator configure
>   INFO: HHH000107: Forcing table use for sequence-style generator due to pooled optimizer selection where db does not support pooled sequences

As you don't have that table, you get an error.

There are several solutions:

1. Change the allocation size to 1

   ```
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen", 
           sequenceName = "GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID", 
           allocationSize = 1)
   ```
2. Create the necessary table instead and populate it with 1 row:

   ```sql
   drop sequence GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID;
   commit;
   create table GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID (
       next_val INTEGER NOT NULL
   );
   commit;
   insert into GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID (next_val) values (1);
   commit;
   ```
3. Create a trigger to assign the id (or, if you are using Firebird 3, you could also declare the column to be [`GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity))

   ```sql
   set term #;
   create trigger user_detail_bi before insert on user_detail
   as
   begin
      new.id = next value for GEN_USER_DETAIL_ID;
   end#
   set term ;#
   commit;
   ```

   and change the `@GeneratedValue` to `IDENTITY`:

   ```
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   ```

Options 2 and 3 are probably better for performance.

Comment: cant hibernate use insert-returning ? then perhaps using generator would be possible without triggers

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes it can use `insert .. returning`, that is used with option 3: `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`, but that will need a trigger or a - Firebird 3 - identity column.